# R - addtable2plot() not displaying dataframe after plot()

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, time-series

So I'm having problems in R because I'm trying to add a dataframe into the blank space of a plot using addtable2plot() but it's not displaying the desired dataframe.

My plot is the forecast of a time series model which I called `model`, so the plot is given by

```
plot(forecast(model),6)
```

which yields

[image]

The dataframe is given by `df<-data.frame(forecast(model,6))[,1:3]` with output

`Point.Forecast    Lo.80    Hi.80
Jun 2017       174.3482 157.4225 191.2738
Jul 2017       174.3574 155.0521 193.6627
Aug 2017       172.4448 151.0009 193.8887
Sep 2017       175.8619 152.4541 199.2697
Oct 2017       179.7774 154.5395 205.0152
Nov 2017       176.8982 149.9368 203.8597`

and the way I'm trying to display the dataframe onto the plot is  `addtable2plot(.5,8,df,bty="o",display.rownames=TRUE,hlines=TRUE,vlines=TRUE,title="My forecast")` but this is not displaying the dataframe.

It's strange because the example coming from the documentation works perfect as you can see [image]

So it looks like addtable2plot() doesn't work together with plot() but I can't find a reference where this is mentioned explicitly or an alternative to what I want to achieve.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You are displaying your table at (0.5,8) (x,y) coordinates. Your x axis start at ,maybe, 1995, so 0.5 is far to the left. Try (2000,200). `addtable2plot(2000,200,df,bty="o",display.rownames=TRUE,hlines=TRUE,vlines=TRUE,title="My forecast")`

Comment: I feel foolish, you're right. Now I can see the dataframe I want. I'm choosing your answer if you put your comment as answer..

Comment: Is there a way to display the dataframe smaller so that it fits into the blank space?

Comment: I think you can use the`cex` option. Try `addtable2plot(2000,200,df,bty="o",display.rownames=TRUE,hlin‌​es=TRUE,vlines=TRUE,‌​title="My forecast", cex=0.7)`

Comment: Wow thanks, it works! Actually I was trying to add the forecast of the next two years (24 months) into the plot of my forecast but the dataframe seemed to be too large and now I can add it without problem! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set up your table coordinates (x,y) properly. Something arround (2000,200) in your case.
`addtable2plot(2000,200,df,bty="o",display.rownames=TRUE,hlin‌​es=TRUE,vlines=TRUE,‌​title="My forecast")`

Comment: Perfect, also the cex parameter is very useful because I want to include the forecast of the next two years and the dataframe becomes bigger but now I can make it smaller. Thanks